# make javascript loading functions to execute one after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where in I execute 2 functions. When I view it in the browser, I get 2 loading symbols which i use for showing the loading of data.

I wanted to know if there is a way to execute each function, one after the other, since I can avoid the 2 loading symbols. I don't want to call the second function inside the first function as a solution.

The code is as shown below:

```
function ABCD() {
   function x();
   function y();
}
```

I want function x() to complete its execution and then start with function y()

Comment: that is the default nature of javascript.... with one exception if `x` has an asynchronous method call then execution of `y` will not wait for the asynchronous method to finish

Comment: Use jQuery promises and `then` to chain them sequentially or `$.when` to wait for them all to finish. Please show the rest of your code to get a better example.

Comment: Make sure to hide the content at the end of the first funciton. Then show the other content in the second function and hide it again at the end of the second function. Are you handling it in that way?

Comment: @plalx: going by the use of the term "loading symbols", I think we can assume ajax calls inside the two functions.

Comment: yes i make synchronous calls inside each of those functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your functions return jQuery promises, you can do something like this:

```
function ABCD() {
   // return the sequential promises
   return x().then(y);  // or return x().done(y); if you want a result after first one only
}
```

then outside you can wait for both with a call like this:

```
ABCD().done(function(){
    alert("both complete");
});
```

if `x` and `y` make an ajax call just return that, as it is already a promise:

e.g.

```
  function x(){
      return $.ajax(...);
  }

  function y(){
      return $.ajax(...);
  }
```

**Working Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9e5rx2bx/2/

Note: the example uses `Deferred` and `setTimeout` to simulate the ajax loads. Have the console open to see the log activity.

The older (non-promise way) would be using callbacks, however the exact implementation depends on your actual current code (which is not shown):

This is a preferred way of solving this type of issue since jQuery 1.5.

Comment: i get an error with using "then" or "done". can you please explain me what promise is.

Comment: @Nikki: What version of jQuery are you using? Promises are a relatively recent addition.

Comment: @Nikki... Does the JSFiddle work for you? (it should). We would need to see the rest of your code to see how you are using the above suggestions/samples.

Comment: Downvoter: please try the fiddle yourself before assuming anything :P This code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla js option (note the callback function is `x()` has been made optional (i.e. `x()` executes just fine without a callback). [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/nz262yyo/)

```
function y() {
    //execute code
}

function x(callback) {
    //execute code
    if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}

function ABCD() {
   x(y());   
}

ABCD();
```

Alternate version with @TrueBlueAussie's suggestion: [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/nz262yyo/5/)

```
function x(callback) {
    //execute code
    if(callback) callback()
}
```

Comment: `if(callback == undefined)` will blow up immediately on the next line.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie good catch... I was testing it in the fiddle and swapped the `!=` for `==`

Comment: I realized that `typeof(callback) === 'function'` will be way more reliable and better suited to this use case

Comment: it is usually sufficient to test only `if (callback) callback()` or even the simpler `callback && callback()`